# how to send data from j2se sever to j2me client

Tags: java-me, java

i have coded server in j2se and client in j2me. i am able to send data from client to server using OutputStream but unable to read the data using InputStream in client and even unable to send data from server using OutputStream. can anyone please help me i am struck here

Comment: please post code [with exception, if any]

Comment: If you're unable to send data from the server then you won't be able to read it on the client. What error messages do you receive when you send the data on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tech tip 10 years ago that might help. It doesn't seem to be available on the Oracle site anymore, but it's accessible from the Internet Archive here: [Client-Server Communication over HTTP using Midlets and Servlets](http://web.archive.org/web/20040408065913/http://java.sun.com/developer/J2METechTips/2001/tt0820.html).